# Objective C : Clean code Ternary operator creating NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, coding-style, ternary-operator

I would like to know the general opinion about a situation that I have had several times during my development experience.
The question itself is about to know which one is the cleanest code.

Plenty of times I have to do a request to the server, where I need to send a NSDictionary with different key/values. The thing is, just if the value exists send the parameter other case don't send it.

So, typical solution could be use an `if` statement:

**A)**

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
if (param1) {
    parameters[key1] = param1;
}
if (param2) {
    parameters[key2] = param2;
}
.....
```

Or the alternative

**B)**

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
if (param1) parameters[key1] = param1;
if (param2) parameters[key2] = param2;
.....
```

But on the other hand you can use a ternary operator `?` (I prefer this solution), so:

**C)**

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
param1 ? parameters[key1] = param1 : nil;
param2 ? parameters[key2] = param2 : nil;
.....
```

And also and alternative

**D)**

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
param1 ? parameters[key1] = param1 : ^{}();
param2 ? parameters[key2] = param2 : ^{}();
.....
```

Which one do you prefer? or if you have a better idea, please let me know

Thanks!!

**UPDATE**

In the examples that I have showed, the conditional are quite simples, just `param1!=nil` but usually I have different conditions. For instance, if the parameter is a NSUInteger and I just going to send it if it is different than `NSNotFound`. 
So it could be like:

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
param1!=NSNotFound ? parameters[key1] = @(param1) : nil;
param2!=NSNotFound ? parameters[key2] = @(param2) : nil;
```

Comment: For this case, i prefer using set​Value:​for​Key:​ instead of ternary. It is nil-safe and much cleaner imho. ref: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutabledictionary/1416335-setvalue?language=objc

Comment: Well, in the example can fit. But is not useful always. If the parameter for instance is a `NSUInteger` and we just send the parameter if it different to `NSNotFound` or `-1` or similar.... isn't valid the option `setValue:forKey` because a `@(-1)` is an object and `@(NSNotFound)` also.
Your suggestion will require a previous transform to object just in a concrete situation.

Comment: Lastly, With `setValue:forKey` you can not have a complex condition, you just can use it if your condition is `object!=nil`

Comment: Options C and D should never be used. You never use the result of the ternary operator and you rely on a side effect of evaluating each expression. Very bad practice.

Comment: I've never heard, that a software had had a bug or at least had been unreadable because of choosing the wrong option from the above. I've heard several times, that software didn't go to production level, because the developers endless discussed such trifle. Do you really think, the right answer to this Q makes poor sources good?

Answer (score 1):

The point is: Im happy with ternary operator as far as the code is readable and elegant. I think that a basic condition and simple assignment is easy to understand and clean.

So, given the fact I would decide use a ternary in this case, I would go on C) option. I think that creating an empty block can generate the opposite feeling in terms of readability.

In case of need a more complex condition, I would still go on C) but defining the condition outside in a boolean parameter to make it cleaner. Something like:

```
BOOL isValid = param1 != nil && (param1 > 2 || param1 < -1);
isValid ? parameters[key1] = param1 : nil;
```

Comment: Options C and D should never be used. You never use the result of the ternary operator and you rely on a side effect of evaluating each expression. Very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of cleanness, I would say A is the cleanest and most readable solution. However, in terms of style, I prefer to use the ternary operator rather than the classic if-else structure. Thus, I would chose the C.

Nevertheless, I do not like so much hardcoding `nil` in the else-clause. In tha case, I will chose the C' solution:

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
!param1 ? : parameters[key1] = param1;
!param2 ? : parameters[key2] = param2;
```